# Import a scala object without a package

Tags: scala, sbt

I am attempting to use the github repo: https://github.com/anirudh985/scala-rake

The author of the code does not provide a package name, it is only objects. How can I import this into my local codebase? I am already importing it through sbt:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin).
  settings(
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion),
    buildInfoPackage := "",
    outputStrategy := Some(StdoutOutput)
  ).dependsOn(rake4s)

lazy val rake4s = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/anirudh985/scala-rake.git"))
```

Comment: If it does not have a `package` declaration _(a really bad practice)_, it will be in the default _(root)_ package. Try `import _root_.RAKE`. - However, given the code is not even being maintained and it is not published as a library, I would just copy and paste the code and put a reference to the original source.

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback since this is not supported as you said and there aren't any good supported packages for this algorithm I guess I will use python.